# How to configure bro to ignore traffic from certain subnets?

Tags: bro, zeek

Situation: I have set up a Zeek/Bro IDS and have it listen on one interface (with iptables forwarding traffic.

```
client1 === iptables === client2
               ||
            zeek_ids
```

Problem: Zeek is getting triggered by 127.0.0.1/8 traffic and I cannot find any materials to help me ignore those traffic on Google.

Question: Not to limit to just 127.0.0.0/8 traffic, how can I configure Zeek such that it is able to ignore traffic coming from certain subnets?

Additional information 1: I have attempted to add the subnet (127.0.0.0/8) to `$ZEEK_PREFIX/etc/networks.cfg` and it did nothing

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, all using BPF filters to exclude specific subnet ranges. You can:

- invoke Zeek with `-f` to pass in such a filter,
- add entries to the `capture_filters` table in the scripting layer,
- use the more advanced features of the [`PacketFilter` module](https://docs.zeek.org/en/current/scripts/base/frameworks/packet-filter/main.zeek.html).

A possible BPF filter to use in your case would be `not net 127.0.0.0/8`.